# Bash completion comes back from the dead

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I started with this problem:

[Bash disables autocompletion for some commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349793/why-bash-disables-autocompletion-for-some-commands-and-how-can-i-disable-it)

The only difference was that in my case the command in question was `configure`. I successfully applied the solution described in that question (i.e. you should remove the completion with `complete -r configure`). The problem is... if you try the completion once, it comes back from the dead.

```
$ complete -p configure 
complete -F _configure configure       # Hum... there *is* a completion

$ complete -r configure                # So let's remove it!

$ complete -p configure 
bash: complete: configure: no completion specification   # Ha! It's gone!

                                       # Let's try it now.
$ ./configure <TAB>                    # Damn! It still doesn't work!

$ complete -p configure                # It's back from the dead!!!
complete -F _configure configure
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

**EDIT:**
One more piece of information:

I added `complete -p configure` to my `.bashrc` and then it started giving me this error on startup:

```
bash: complete: configure: no completion specification
```

This is interesting. The completion for `configure` doesn't exist at startup... It seems that some kind of *dynamic* completion definition is happening here.

Comment: Is your goal to permanently disable tab autocomplete for all commands, or just specifically `configure`?

Comment: Just for `configure`.

Comment: `Configure` is a special Linux script, not a command. Your understanding of `complete` is incorrect. `complete -p configure` needs an additional parameter, i.e the word to auto complete as shown in your `complete -F _configure configure` example. To disable tab autocomplete for configure you either need to disable auto completion entirely, which you do not want, or disable autocomplete for filenames. Since complete references commands and configure is not a command but a script it does not work the way you want it to. [Is this related?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162037/276845)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the script for `configure` gets loaded dynamically.

You can confirm that with setting the option that prints all executed commands with `set -x`. And try to autocomplete with TAB.

The clue to find the source is the output of this command

```
dpkg -L bash-completion | xargs egrep '\<_configure\>' 2>/dev/null
```

Just delete the file for `configure` and restart your bash instance or clear with `complete -r configure`.

```
sudo rm /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/configure
```

Comment: Thanks! :)
Just out or curiosity: do you know what this completion actually does (or is supposed to do)? For me, it never did anything besides disabling file completion.

Comment: It tries to run configure with the --help parameter, parse its output for possible options to give in the completion.